# save string query result in variable in sql server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have this query (this is a one slice of my query)

```
DECLARE @Count varchar(max)

SET @Count = ('SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(Id) FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@Tbl))

EXEC (@Count)

DECLARE @CalRemainPage int = convert(int, @Count ) - (3 * 15)
```

and when I run my query I get this error from this slice

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'SELECT TOP 1
>   COUNT(Id) FROM [Sample_Work]' to data type int.

I know my problem is result of `@count`, put the `@count` string instead of result of this

```
DECLARE @CalRemainPage int = convert(int, @Count ) - (3 * 15)
```

How can I save result of `@count` query and use `@count` in other place such as top sample?

Thank you

Comment: top1 count return int so you have this error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not the right way of doing it. Instead of `Exec` use `SP_executesql`to execute your dynamic SQL.

In `SP_executesql` you can declare the variable as `OUTPUT parameter` and you can use it outside of Dynamic query. Try something like this.

```
DECLARE @Count INT,
        @Tbl   VARCHAR(20)='jointest',
        @sql   NVARCHAR(max)

SET @sql = ( 'SELECT  TOP 1 @Count= COUNT(ID) FROM '+ Quotename(@Tbl) )

EXEC Sp_executesql
  @sql,
  N'@Count int output',
  @count output

DECLARE @CalRemainPage INT= @Count - ( 3 * 15 )
```

Comment: thank you for your help, but i want try this
DECLARE CalRemainPage INT= sql - ( 3 * 15 ) 
when i change count to sql i get same error

Comment: @SH.Developer You should not do that. count is already present in `@count` variable then why you want `@sql` there

Comment: i want subtraction count of Id from  (3*15) that count of Id obtained from sql

Comment: i declare sql for this reason,

Comment: @SH.Developer - FYI `@count` variable will be holding the count(id) present in the table. If count of ID in the table is 50 then `@count` will be holding 50. your result will be `50-(3*15) = 45`.